# In what .targets file is the "Package" MSBuild target defined?

Tags: msbuild, package, web-deployment-project, microsoft-web-deploy

This pertains to Web Deploy and/or Web Deployment Projects (not sure what the relation is between those). Simply curious about the constituent Tasks that I might be able to recompose into a customized package Target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The publishing targets for generating msdeploy web packages can be located at :

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
```

In addition to playing with the tasks, there are a variety of properties you can use to redirect the packaging output name, location and configuration....